# Actions on Google webhook call - add a delay to speech response

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant

I'm trying to make my own Google Assistant Actions. I'm sending a Json response back to my Google Assistant. Google Assistant receives the response and reads the text. So far all good.

Now I want to do the following. Google Assistant should read:
"Test 123" and make then a 1 second delay... Then finally read "Test321"

How should I adjust my Json response so that it works with the delay? Is it possible?

[image]

I generate JSON response Object via ASP.NET

My Main Class

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostWebHook()
{

    Google_Assistant_Request_Json.RequestJson request = new Google_Assistant_Request_Json.RequestJson(); //Request Object
    Google_Assistant_Response_Json.ResponseJson response = new Google_Assistant_Response_Json.ResponseJson(); //Response Object

    string body;
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body))
    {
        
        body = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        request = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Google_Assistant_Request_Json.RequestJson>(body);

            response.session.id = request.session.id;
            response.prompt.@override = false;
            response.prompt.firstSimple.speech = "Test123";
            response.prompt.lastSimple.speech = "Test321";
      
    }

    return Ok(response);
}
```

Comment: It isn't clear how you're generating JSON, so it is a little difficult to answer your question with sufficient detail. If you can include the code to show how the JSON is generated, we might be able to be a little more specific.

Comment: @Prisoner I edited my question and added my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use [SSML](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/ssml) as your speech response and to include a [`<break>`](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/ssml#break) tag to generate the pause.

So your SSML might look something like:

```
<speak>
Test 123 <break time="1s"/> Test 321
</speak>
```

Note that this should be what you use for the "speech" field in your response. The "text" field should **not** include the SSML markup and there is no way by default to make sure that the second part of the text appears after a 1 second delay - all the text is shown at once. (There are some advanced techniques that involve the [Interactive Canvas](https://developers.google.com/assistant/interactivecanvas) and the SSML [`<mark>`](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/ssml#mark) tag, however these have some restrictions on their use.)

Based on your code, it might look something like this:

```
response.prompt.firstSimple.speech = "<speak>Test123 <break time='1s'/> Test321</speak>";
response.prompt.firstSimple.text   = "Test123 Test321";
```

or, if you have a good reason to be using both `firstSimple` and `lastSimple`

```
response.prompt.firstSimple.speech = "<speak>Test123 <break time='1s'/></speak>";
response.prompt.firstSimple.text   = "Test123";
response.prompt.lastSimple.speech  = "<speak>Test321</speak>";
response.prompt.lastSimple.text    = "Test321";
```

Comment: I edited my question and added my code. I replaced  firstSimple.speech = "Test123" to firstSimple.speech = "Test 123 <break time=\"1s\"/> Test 321";

Comment: Updated my answer. Note that you must have the <speak> tag as well.